# Positioning Div container

Tags: css, html, position, containers

i have a page containing css menu.

I want to position it where i want. if i do {margin-top: 30pt;} it works but it shift other things or get shifted itself. is there anyway to position it ignoring other elements.

Ignore my bad english.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles.css' />
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10./jquery.min.js'>     </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HELLPO!</h1>
<div id="cssmenu" style = "position: relative; margin-top: 100pt; overflow: hidden;">
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
<li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
<li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we see your CSS file?

Comment: THANKS Alien, it worked

thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Yes , by using position: absolute. Position absolute does not effect the other elements, and does not care about where they are located.

Adjust the px according to what works best.

```
<div id="cssmenu" style = "position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px; overflow: hidden;">
```